# Java Makefile Output Single Executable

Tags: java, makefile

How can I create a Makefile to compile my Java program with a single source file located in `src/Hello.java` to ouput a file that I can run with `./prog`

Answer (score 2):

(1) Take a look at http://ant.apache.org/ - that's a build tool suited to Java better than make. For example check out the `javac` command in ant.

(2) You have to run java programs by running the java virtual machine (`java`) and by telling it what to execute. There is no ./xxx way to run a program in java; that method executes scripts or executable programs, and a compiled java program is bytecode which is neither. What you need is to create a little shell script, call it "Hello", give it execute permissions with `chmod`, its contents should be something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

java -cp . Hello
```

Comment: Well, on Linux, there is binfmt, which allows to actually run ./app.jar.

Comment: Come to think of it, Java installer for Windows registers "jar" extension too so it can be run directly from command line or by clicking on it. The only problem is whether to use console or windowed version of JVM. More exotic platforms may not have such feature, though (HP-UX comes to mind).

Answer (score 2):

Make is not a great tool for building Java programs, primarily because its core design is to identify out-of-date sources (either source or object files) and apply transforms to them. The Java compiler handles this dependency checking already, and defining a Make rule for Java compilation is more trouble than it's worth.

Adrian Smith has already suggested Ant. I'm going to suggest [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) as an alternative.

My main reason for this suggestion is that it's very easy to get a simple project going in Maven: you can tell Maven to create the entire directory structure, and then it just works. And although you may not like the directory structure that Maven creates, there's a benefit to the consistency if you're working in a large project. Maven does have its limitations, and some of them are extremely painful, but you generally won't run into them until you have the knowledge to work around them.

As for running a Java program, you need to invoke the JVM somewhere along the line. A shell script is one approach, but generally it's easier just to invoke the JVM directly. If you create an "executable JAR" (which Maven will do for you, including options to include all dependencies), you can invoke it like this:

```
java -jar executable.jar
```

Comment: The java compiler is fine for compiling single files.  It can compile multiple files to avoid launching a full JVM for each (which used to be abysmally slow).  Make is not a good tool for launching a single command line to process multiple files, hence ant was writtne.